# BCrypt does not compare password correctly

Tags: node.js, authentication, bcrypt

I am currently working on an API on node.js. I have seen other similar posts but the solution does not work for me. Below are my codes to retrieve user by email and compare the password. I enter the correct credentials but the compare is always returning false. Am I missing out something?

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;

app.post('/auth', function (req, response) {

let query = `select * from users where email = "${req.body.email}"`;

console.warn(req.body.email);
databaseConnector.query(query, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error, 'Error occurred with /auth/ API...');
    }
    if (result.length > 0) {

        console.warn(req.body.password, result[0].password);

        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, result[0].password, function (err, res) {
            console.warn(res, 'bcryot response')
            // if res == true, password matched
            // else wrong password
            if (res) {
                var token = jwt.sign({ userID: result.id }, 'todo-app-super-shared-secret', { expiresIn: '2h' });

                response.send({
                    token: token,
                    id: result[0].id,
                    firstName: result[0].firstName
                })
            }
            else {
                return response.sendStatus(401);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        return response.sendStatus(401);
    }
})
});
```

Comment: SQL injection 101

Comment: Can you post the code where you store the password?

Comment: you should check the req.body.password and result[0].password.maybe anyone of them giving null value.thats why you getting false

Comment: @Konrad you mean it's not safe?

Comment: @ipizzinidev it's in phpmyadmin database

Comment: Yee, a malicious can read/delete your entire database, by changing `req.body.email`